# Rows that appear in two separate txt files, remove from one txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Pretty new to python. My issue is that I have one txt file ('A.txt') that has a bunch of columns in it and a second txt file ('B.txt) that has different data. However, some of the data that's in B also shows up in A. Example:

```
A.txt:

name1 x1 y1
name2 x2 y2
name3 x3 y3
name4 x4 y4
name5 x5 y5
name6 x6 y6
...

B.txt
namea xa ya
name2 x2 y2
name3 x3 y3
nameb xb yb
namec xc yc 
...
```

I want everything in B.txt that shows up in A.txt to be removed from A.txt
I realize this has been asked before, but I have tried the advice that was given to people asking a similar question, but it doesn't work for me.

So far I have:

```
tot = 0
with open('B.txt', 'r') as f1:
    for a in f1:
        WR = a.strip().split()

        with open('A.txt', 'r+') as f2:
            for b in f2:
                l = b.strip().split()

                if WR not in l:
                    print l
                    tot += 1

                #I've done it the following way and also doesn't give the      
                #output I need
                #if WR == l: #find duplicates
                #    continue
                #else:
                #    print l
print tot
```

When I run this I get back what I think is the answer (file A has 2060 file B has 154) but repeated 154 times. 
So example of what I mean is:

```
A.txt:
name1 x1 y1
name4 x4 y4
name5 x5 y5
name6 x6 y6
...
name1 x1 y1
name4 x4 y4
name5 x5 y5
name6 x6 y6
...    
name1 x1 y1
name4 x4 y4
name5 x5 y5
name6 x6 y6
...
name1 x1 y1
name4 x4 y4
name5 x5 y5
name6 x6 y6
...
```

I only want it to look like:

```
A.txt:
name1 x1 y1
name4 x4 y4
name5 x5 y5
name6 x6 y6
...
```

Like I've said, I've already looked at the other similar questions and tried what they did and it's giving me this repeating answer. Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your A and B files so just check and let me know if its correct

```
tot = 0
f1 = open('B.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('A.txt', 'r')

lista = []
for line in f1:
    line.strip()
    lista.append(line)

listb = []
for line in f2:
    line.strip()
    listb.append(line)

for b in listb:
    if b in lista:
        continue
    else:
        print(b)
        tot+=1
```

This code prints the line, but if you want you can write it to a file too

Comment: So it only gives me 154 lines back, and I should be getting 2044. (I was able to make a code that showed me how many duplicates there were that looked almost exactly like the code I provided). I think your solution is close!